# How do I find the busiest month using sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I am trying to find the busiest month (which month had the most guests) with the CheckIn attribute.
This is my table:

```
Reservation
```

- ReservationNumber (Primary Key)  Data Type: Integer
- CheckIN Data type: DateTime example: 2011-10-31
- CheckOut Data type: DateTime example: 2011-10-31
- GuestID Data type: Integer
- RoomNumber Data type: Integer

I understand that I would have to use GROUP BY but I don't know how I would be able to separate the checkin dates by month. I tried MONTH() but sql says no such function. Please help.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should try this:

```
SELECT strftime('%m', CheckIN) AS month, COUNT(GuestID) AS tot
FROM reservation
GROUP BY month
ORDER by tot DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have a Date type (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). So i would guess it is storing is as a blob which would be an integer stored as epoch number, you can use http://www.epochconverter.com/ to convert the month you want into epoch and then search over the range between the start of the month and the beginning of the month.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count(`ReservationNumber`) FROM `Reservation` GROUP BY strftime('%m', `CheckIN`) ORDER BY count(`ReservationNumber`) DESC